# Plotting volatility and add predicted values

Tags: r

apparently, I want to plot the volatility and add the predicted values together, but the predicted values have less lines than the predicted values (accounts for the last third of the volatility). I want to add the predicted values at the right spot in the same graph as the volatility to show the changes.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with some data and the desired output.

Comment: Let's say volatitly is: 

1) 110.54
2) 110.84
3) 110.12
4) 109.96
5) 110.08
6) 110.96

and predicted values for 5) and 6) are:

106.54
106.32

I want to plot the whole time-series (all 6) with the predicted values on spot 5 and 6.